# Why Is This Method Not Visible from Django Custom Manager?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two Django models, one that stores promotion codes and another that tracks who redeemed a particular promotion code.  I'm trying to create an instance method that determines whether or not a specific user has redeemed a specific code.  The problem is that I'm not seeing one of my PromotionManager methods, 'redeemed_by_user'.  Here are my classes:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class PromotionManager(models.Manager):
    def redeemed_by_user(self, promotion, user):
        redemption_count = PromotionRedeemed.objects.filter(promotion=promotion, redeemer=user).count()
        if redemption_count == 1:
            return True
        elif redemption_count == 0;
            return False
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid redemption count')

class Promotion(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    objects = PromotionManager()

class PromotionRedeemed(models.Model):
    promotion = models.ForeignKey('Promotion')
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

If I start the the Django extension shell_plus and do the following:

```
In [1]: user = User.objects.get(username='smith')
In [2]: promotion = Promotion.objects.get(code='bigsale')
```

and then I do this:

```
In [3]: dir(promotion)
```

I don't see the redeemed by user method.  I was under the impression that I could move methods like this from my class to a custom manager class.  Is that not the case?  If so, can anyone explain why?  As I understand it, class manager methods are supposed to act on table-level queries and class intance methods on row-level objects.  Isn't objects.filter acting on the table level?  I tried moving the method back to the Promotion class and I can see it there but I'd just like to understand why I can't see it in the manager class.

Comment: What about `dir(promotion.objects)`? `redeemed_by_user` - is a manager method, not promotion object or class.

Comment: have you tried print(promotion.code) in the shell?

Comment: Yea, I actually can see 'promotion.objects' and when I try to 'dir' it, the shell tells me "AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via Promotion instances".  That explains the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are seeing is absolutely correct but there is small correction that you should make. When you do a `dir(some_instance)` then you see a property named objects .

```
objects = PromotionManager()
```

This line sets all the manager methods to the objects property so if you try to access the method via `some_instance.objects.method_name` then you will be able to access it although you can't use it because Django doesn't allow this. You will see an error like manager methods are not accessible from instances. dir is supposed to show only those methods which are accessible from your model instance.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs,

> A Manager is the interface through which database query operations are provided to Django models. By default, Django adds a Manager with the name "objects" to every Django model class.
>
> A model’s manager is an object through which Django models perform database queries. Each Django model has at least one manager, and you can create custom managers in order to customize database access.
>
> Adding extra manager methods(custom managers) is the preferred way to add “table-level” functionality to your models whereas for “row-level” functionality use model methods.

**Objects is a special attribute through which you query your database. It’s an instance of the class django.db.models.Manager; it’s where all the default methods for performing queries against the entire model class — all(), get(), filter(), etc**.

The `dir()` function, with an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object.

If you `dir(promotion)`, `promotion` is an instance of `Promotion` Model object. It returns the attributes of a `Promotion` instance, which includes the `objects` attribute. But, you defined `objects` as `PromotionManager()`, and the `redeemed_by_user()` is a method of the Manager instance.

If you `dir(promotion.objects)` , django would raise an error, `AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via Poke instances`. Because, its true. `objects` is a `Manager` available at the class level, not to the instances.

[From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects),

> Managers are accessible only via model classes, rather than from model instances, to enforce a separation between “table-level” operations and “record-level” operations.

So, if you `dir(Promotion.objects)`, you could see all custom methods defined in the Manager instance of the model.

Answer (score 0):

You use `dir` on the wrong object.

Moreover, you replaced default manager with yours.
The first manager applied to a model class has special meaning for Django, and is a default one, so add own manager this way, please:

```
objects = models.Manager()
<your_custom_name> = PromotionManager()
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine to replace the default manager. If Django requires a `models.Manager` instance, it will use the base manager instead.

Comment: @knbk: has consequences, first manager (a default) has special status. It may cause unpredictable results from QuerySets, because that manager is used by Django itself.
I am referring to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Model._default_manager

Comment: "As a result, it’s a good idea to be careful in your choice of default manager in order to avoid a situation **where overriding get_queryset() results in an inability to retrieve objects you’d like to work with.**" The docs mention one very specific scenario where you have to be careful, which doesn't apply here. It's in no way unpredictable.

Comment: ... if you add new methods to the default manager nobody (at least at first look) will expect them there, the code must speak for itself.

Comment: So now they have to discover the second manager instead of the methods on a custom manager? Either way they have to look through the code and/or project documentation.